# English to Spanish translator using java

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm learning java GUI on my own and trying to make a simple translator that translates "how are you?" to "Como estas?" with Translate button. There are two textAreas in my code, and I would like to enter English sentences in textArea1 and get results in textArea2. Tried to make the translate button work like "=" button of calculator but I failed, maybe I still don't understand how to use actionListener and actionPerformed clearly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I made main_Translator.java and Translator.java. If possible, I want to merge them. don't know how though..

```
//Translator.java
package Translator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Translator /*implements ActionListener*/{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();

  public Translator(){
    frame.setSize(600,800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Translator"); 

    frame.add(panel);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,2);
    panel.setBorder(border); 

    Color b=new Color(240,215,160); 
    panel.setBackground(b);    

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Input: ");
    Font labelFont1 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,22);
    label1.setFont(labelFont1);
    panel.add(label1);

    JTextArea textarea1 = new JTextArea(6,32);

    panel.add(textarea1);
    textarea1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Border tborder1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE,1);
    textarea1.setBorder(tborder1);
    Font font1 = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN,22);
    textarea1.setFont(font1);
    textarea1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    textarea1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2,10));
    textarea1.setLineWrap(true);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Output: ");
    label2.setFont(labelFont1);
    panel.add(label2);

    JTextArea textarea2 = new JTextArea(6,32);
    panel.add(textarea2);
    textarea2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Border tborder2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE,1);
    textarea2.setBorder(tborder2);
    textarea2.setFont(font1);
    textarea2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    textarea2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2,10));
    textarea2.setLineWrap(true);

    JComboBox language = new JComboBox();
    panel.add(language);
    language.setFont(font1);
    language.addItem("Español");

    JButton transButton = new JButton("Translate");
    transButton.setFont(font1);
    transButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30)); 
    panel.add(transButton);

}
}
```

and this is main_Translator.java.

```
//main_Translator.java
package Translator;

public class main_Translator { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Translator trans = new Translator();
  }
} 
//when I press a putton (Greetings)
```

Comment: Please read about Java naming conventions. No underbars in class names. And they go UpperCase.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the entirety of `main_Translator.java` and you are simply looking to move the main method, just copy it over into `Translator.java` below the constructor. It should work exactly the same.